# How to get host in Node when using nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I created a node server and I can get the request host using `req.headers.host`,But when I use nginx to proxy, How can I get the request host in Node?

Comment: add this to your nginx config.

     `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`